# Miners ignore storage barn near the mine

Tags: banished

I've built a separate storage barn near mines for my miners. But it seems that they completely ignore it. They put iron near the mine and no one takes resources to the storage. How can I make them put resources there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iron (and coal and stone and wood) do not go in storage barns.  They go in the open-air stockpiles.  You're probably best off just building sufficient stockpile space next to your mine.  Use your markets to get the materials disbursed throughout the map.

Disbursing stone, however, through your town is actually a little problematic.  Marketplace vendors don't pull stone to the markets so it will always just end up in the stockpile next to your quarry or trading post.  Not much you can do about this.

Comment: np.  By the way, I was wrong about markets -- they do stock iron/coal, so I updated my answer.